# Parrot OS unmet dependencies, Held Broken Packages

Tags: linux, apt-get

I'm trying to install samba on parrot OS, the command I'm using is `sudo apt install smbclient`. the output I get is this. please help.

> sudo apt-get install samba
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree... Done
> Reading state information... Done
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
> requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
> distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
> or been moved out of Incoming.
> The following information may help to resolve the situation:\
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> samba : Depends: python3-samba but it is not going to be installed
> Depends: samba-common (= 2:4.13.13+dfsg-1~deb11u5) but 2:4.17.8+dfsg-1~bpo11+1 is to be installed
> Depends: samba-common-bin (= 2:4.13.13+dfsg-1~deb11u5) but it is not going to be installed
> Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:4.13.13+dfsg-1~deb11u5) but 2:4.17.8+dfsg-1~bpo11+1 is to be installed
> Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.13.13+dfsg-1~deb11u5) but it is not going to be installed
> Recommends: samba-dsdb-modules but it is not going to be installed
> Recommends: samba-vfs-modules but it is not going to be installed
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Try   

sudo apt-get --fix-missing update to get missing updates.


and


sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  to install new dependecies

Answer (score 1):

Remove all unmet dependencies

```
sudo apt remove samba-common samba-common-bin libwbclient0 samba-libs
```

Install smbclient

```
sudo apt install smbclient
```

It still not working because more unmet dependencies
Remove smbclient and its dependencies

```
sudo apt remove smbclient
```

```
sudo apt purge smbclient
```

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Reinstall

```
sudo apt install smbclient
```

And it works